# Clicking New field on /admin/settings/field/new hangs site

Tags: field, error, settings

Running 3.2.4, and clicking on "new field" which calls `/[admin]/settings/fields/new` times out on our AWS servers where the DB is hosted in the cloud. It isn't an issue when everything's running `localhost`, but that's the only things we can see as a difference between them.

On the AWS hosted site, the CP and front end become unresponsive for that user in that browser for 15-20 minutes, but a newly created session from another browser works.

Could anyone else who similarly has their DB hosted on another machine try clicking Settings->Fields->New and see if it returns fast?

Comment: Tons of Craft 3 installs running on AWS (including id.craftcms.com/api.craftcms.com/etc.) so guessing it depends on your specific environment. Tried checking AWS and Craft/PHP log files to see where the hangup occurs?

Answer (score 1):

We discovered that the `verbb/icon-picker` plugin makes a call out to retrieve a file from it's `cpresources` cache and this was done with a fully qualified URL. Our AWS machines in CI/CD can be auto-provisioned and as such won't have their own name in the `/etc/hosts` file. So a call to `https://fully.qualified.url/cpresources/577762fa/json/font-awesome.json?v=1556336828` was failing and hanging the site because it tried to get it five times in a row.

I've registered an issue with the Verbb folks, and put a PR together, so crossing my fingers!